# How to print specific pages from PrintDocument programmatically?

Tags: c#, printing

Is there a way to print only selected pages from a `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` programmatically (eg. page 3-5)?

I am using this code:

```
myPrintDocument.Print();
```

But that way I can't skip pages programmatically. I've thought about the possibility to show a [modified version of the PrintDialog class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/TopMostPrintDlg.aspx), skip the pages I don't want, print the document and programmatically close the PrintDialog window (so that it only flashes by). But that would be a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `PrinterSettings` in the `PrintDocument.BeginPrint` event.

The `PrintDocument.PrintPage` event, where you put your printing code will be raised by the Print Controller for Every Page up to the last page set in the `PrinterSettings`.  For example, if you have a 10 page `PrintDocument` and you set the `PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 5`, then the print controller will raise the `PrintPage` event for every Page until it processes the 5th Page.

If you are skipping pages, for example `PrinterSettings.FromPage = 3` to `ToPage = 5`, then the print controller will raise a `PrintPage` event 3 times.  That is one `PrintPage` event per count from 3 to 5 inclusive.

The print controller does not decide what Content gets printed by the `PrintPage` event.  It only raises the event once per each counted page in your range.  For example, if you specify `FromPage = 4` to `FromPage = 6`, the print controller would raise the exact same amount of `PrintPage` events and it doesn't even know the difference! It does not know which page it is printing with the `PrintPage` event.  It only knows to raise the `PrintPage` event 3 times.

My point is that your Code in the `PrintPage` event must process all of your skipped pages without Drawing anything.  Then your Code in that SAME `PrintPage` event must process and Draw the "current page" that you want to print, and then return so the print controller can raise the next `PrintPage` event.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
void Setup_Printing()
{
  myPrintDocument.BeginPrint += On_BeginPrint;
  myPrintDocument.PrintPage += On_PrintPage;
}

// Page Index variable
int indexCuurentPage = 0;

void On_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
  indexCuurentPage = 0;
  ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
  ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.FromPage = 3;
  ((PrintDocument)sender).PrinterSettings.ToPage = 5;
}


void On_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppea)
{
  // Set up a loop to process pages.
  bool bProcessingPages = true;
  while (bProcessingPages)
  {
    indexCurrentPage++;

    // Set isPageInRange flag to true if this indexCurrentPage is in the selected range of pages
    bool isPageInRange = (theCurrentPage >= ppea.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.FromPage);
    isPageInRange = isPageInRange && (theCurrentPage =< ppea.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.ToPage);

    if (isPageInRange)
    {
      // Process your data and print this page then exit the loop.  
      try
      {
        //// TO DO - Process Data ////
        //// TO DO - Draw Data to ppea.Graphics ////
        // Note:  Do not set the ppea.HasMorePages to true.  Let the Printer Controller do it.
      }
      catch
      {
        // Abort printing more pages if there was an error.
        ppea.HasMorePages = false;
      }
      // Set the loop exit flag.  We could use "return;" instead if we do not want to do more.
      bProcessingPages = false;
    }
    else
    {
      // Process your data and Do Not Draw on the ppea.Graphics.
      try
      {
        //// TO DO - Process Data ////
      }
      catch
      {
        // Abort printing more pages if there was an error.
        ppea.HasMorePages = false;
        // Set the loop exit flag.  We could use "return;" instead if we do not want to do more.
        bProcessingPages = false;
      }
      // Stay in the processing loop until you either need to actually Print a Page
      // or until you run out of data and pages to print.
    }

    // check to see if we ran out of pages to print
    if (indexCurrentPage >= ppea.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.ToPage)
    {
      // Done.  We do not need to set the HasMorePages = false
      bProcessingPages = false;
    }
  } // end while processing pages

  // The print controller will decide to raise the next PrintPage event if it needs to.
  // If You set the ppea.HasMorePages = false, then it will stop any more page events. 
  // If You set the ppea.HasMorePages = true, 
  //    then I'm not sure what the print controller will do if it ran out of pages!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
PrinterSettings printSettings = new PrinterSettings()
            {
                FromPage = 3,
                ToPage = 5
            };
PrintDocument myPrintDocument = new PrintDocument()
            {
                PrinterSettings = printSettings
            };
myPrintDocument.Print();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer! I am not familiar with that syntax you're using so to speak (couldn't get it to work with the brackets after the parenthesis) But tried with

`PrinterSettings printSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printSettings.FromPage = 3;
printSettings.ToPage = 5;
myPrintDocument.PrinterSettings = printSettings;
myPrintDocument.Print();` 

But it still printed all pages in the document and not only 3-5..?

Comment: Glad you got it working! Can you mark it as an answer for future reference. My apologies on the syntax - I'm using the "object initializer" syntax to create the objects. It was introduced in .Net 3, I believe, so if you're using a .Net version below that, it won't be available.

Comment: Ah! I see. No I did not get it working (as I said at the end of my comment), but that is because from what I understand now, setting the FromPage and ToPage properties doesn't do much, it's still up to me to make sure that pages outide of that range isn't printed... Thanks though!

Comment: @Patrick You forgot to set the PrintRange property of the PrinterSettings. `PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings(){ FromPage = 3, ToPage = 5, PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages }`;

Comment: @LamdaComplex, `PrintRange.SomePages` seems to make no difference even though it logically should. Perhaps the `PrintController` needs to actively skip pages that aren't in the range using the `PrinterSettings`...