# Print pages NOT in the List

Tags: c#, printdocument

I have a `int` list containing the pages I **DON'T** want to print.

Let's call it `skipPages`.

When I tried to put the actual printing part inside the `if(skipPages.IndexOf(currentPage)<0)` statement, it print me blank pages.

```
public void printPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    List<int> skipPages = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6 };
    if(currentPage<totalPage) e.HasMorePages = true;
    else e.HasMorePages = false;

    if(skipPages.IndexOf(currentPage)<0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            currentPage.ToString(),
            new Font("Times New Roman",12),
            new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
            new Point(10,10));
    }
    currentPage++;

}
```

And when I tried to put the `e.HasMorePages = true` inside it, it just stop everything after the first skip page.

```
public void printPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    List<int> skipPages = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6 };
    if(currentPage<totalPage && skipPages.IndexOf(currentPage)<0) e.HasMorePages = true;
    else e.HasMorePages = false;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        currentPage.ToString(),
        new Font("Times New Roman",12),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
        new Point(10,10));
    currentPage++;

}
```

Could somebody please teach me how to correctly set it up, please!?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi PiggyChu515, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post the relevant code as we don't have much to go on with.

Comment: i think this link can be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761897/how-to-print-specific-pages-from-printdocument-programmatically

Comment: @Francis: I added the code, hope it will help!

Comment: @Alireza: The example teach me how to print a **range** of pages, which is NOT what I'm trying to do. I tried to **skip** pages, which could be page 2,5,6 or 4,7,12,14,15,19. But thanks anyway!

Comment: The PrintPage event is fired for every page.  If you don't draw anything then you get a blank page.  You must therefore increment the *currentPage* variable to arrive at a page you do want to print.  That makes e.HasMorePages a bit tricky to set correctly, best way to get it right is to do the test up front, starting with the BeginPrint event.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for your comment! I solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrintPage event is fired for every page, so all you have to do is to skip the `currentPage` which is in the List.

You also need a mechanism to check if the last few pages are in the skip list, to avoid printing blank pages in the end.

```
List<int> skipPages = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6 };

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    currentPage = 0;
}

public void printPage(object sender,System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    bool f = false;
    int c = currentPage + 1;

    //Mechanism to check for the last few pages.
    while(skipPages.IndexOf(c)>=0) c++;
    if(c>=totalPages) f=false;
    else f=true;

    while(skipPages.IndexOf(currentPage)>=0) currentPage++; //Actual skipping part.
    if(currentPage<totalPage-1) e.HasMorePages = f;
    else e.HasMorePages = false;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(
         currentPage.ToString(),
         new Font("Times New Roman",12),
         new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
         new Point(10,10));
    currentPage++;
}
```

Comment: You did not get it correct.  Imagine what happens when either the first or the last page is in the skipPages list.  The e.HasMorePages assignment needs to be done *after* that while loop so you don't get an extra blank page.  And you really do need the BeginPrint event as well, both to reset the currentPage variable back to 0 and to advance it beyond any skipped pages.  So the *skipPages* variable can't be a local variable, move it out of the method.

Comment: I updated it! Please check if I do it right!? Thanks!

Comment: I thought it might be easier to edit the snippet instead.  Done.

Comment: Thanks! But if you put the `while` loop in the `BeginPrint`, does it still need to put it in the `printPage`!?