# Print only every second page from a word document. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, ms-word, cpu-word

I want to make a windows form program in C# that makes a word document from another and change some text in it. That's done but I want to make a print button too and I need to print the document on one sheet.

I want to print the 2 paged document on one sheet and the printer what the program need to use cant do it one go I need to put back the paper.

I tried some methods but none of them worked. I searched for about 3 days got some solutions but none of them worked. Every time the program want to print the 2 page on separate sheet and when I tried to print only the second page again that was the problem, the program started from page one and that go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Print only every second page from a word document. How can I do that?

If you want to specify the pages to be printed take a look at this [How to print specific pages from PrintDocument programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761897/how-to-print-specific-pages-from-printdocument-programmatically)

> I want to print the 2 paged document on one sheet and the printer what the program need to use cant do it one go I need to put back the paper.

Its either resize the print document to fit both into a single sheet or if you want to print back-to-back i.e. Duplex Printing, that is specific to the printer you have and you might want to show a print dialog like this;

[image: Sample Print Dialog]

Which will further lead you to the printer properties specific to the one you use, like this;

[image: Sample Printer Properties]

For the code in showing this print dialog;

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog {
   Document = yourPrintDocument
};
printDialog.ShowDialog();
```